# Copy a field's value to another field and modify it

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, hooks

I have content type "Video"
When i do a new "video" I have a field "iframe_vimeo" thats it contains a value of the iframe's video link.

I want to do some modifications with the value of this field and put the result in a new field "Link Modificated"

I try to make an example:
I create a new Video:

> - I fill the fields.
> - My field "iframe_vimeo" has the value

```
"<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/66865270?color=ff0179" width="640"
> height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
> allowfullscreen></iframe>"
```

> - I save and create the Video

Now i want to obtain the value of my "iframe_vimeo" and make some modifications  and fill my field "Link Modificated" with the result and save it.

field "Link Modificated" result value =

```
"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/116320565_100x75.jpg?r=pad"
```

I saw the function mymodule_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) but i dont know to work it.
I need some help please!

EDIT:  the field "iframe_vimeo" It's not an obligatory field, but always its fill, i want to fill the other field ("Link Modificated") with the modifications. Besides, if someone edit a Video Content and modify the field "iframe_vimeo"I will have the refill the field "Link Modificated" with the new modifications value.

Thanks, very much

Comment: Depending on your precise needs, you might want to look at `hook_node_presave` instead`

Comment: It depends. You want to save a modified version of the iframe_vimeo be always saved in another field when the node is modified? Then, probably hook_node_presave is a good option. If that link_modificated field is filled only in certain circumstances you may need to use other ways. I guess it would be good if you explain better your use case. Also, why you need the modified value? Again, if you explain your needs we may suggest a better approach.

Comment: @sanzante the field "iframe_vimeo" It's not an obligatory field, but always its fill i want to  fill the other field Link Modificated) with the modifications. Besides if someone Edit the Video Content and modify the field "iframe_vimeo" i will have the refill  the field "Link Modificated".

Comment: So a better title for this question would be: "Save a field value derived from another field each time a content is saved to the database", right?

Comment: yes, this is perfect! Sorry... My English is very bad. I tried to put my best

Comment: Then I suggest going with @beltouche's solution.

Comment: yes, works fine! thanks to much for the help to both

Comment: It would be great if you post your solution and select it as the right answer. This way the question is officially answered, other people see an example on how to solve this program and you would get some reputation (I'll happily upvote your answer, for example).